# Multiple Web/Api Projects Open on separated chrome windows with visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have this issue when i run my multiple projects on visual studio it opens multiple google chrome windows, it used to be opening in one window by separated tabs (before newest update, but i assume some option might be gone?). how to make it run within one window but within separated tabs?

Comment: How do you run a multiple projects? I thought there should always be a "startup project"

Comment: @Baruch you can right click on solution and go to `properties` then on `common properties` tab find `startup project` then you can easily choose `multiple startup projects`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the issue was caused by `Stop debugger when browser window is closed` within options, i disabled this and issue is fixed.

**Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects**

- Disable "Stop debugger when browser window is closed".

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, he meant a few projects, not a single project that is run several times. No?

Comment: @Baruch answered in question's comment